# Gentoo and Grub2: system hangs when using GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

Tags: gentoo, grub2

I've successfully installed Gentoo as a VirtualBox Guest VM following the handbook (http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml). Everything in order, but I want to change the default resolution of my console, after grub2 loads.

But, when changing my `/etc/default/grub` file and adding:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

.. the system successfully starts grub2, but then hangs when loading the kernel. On-screen it just displays 'Loading kernel such-and-such'.

Since the liveCD image has no problem with running the console in a higher resolutions, it seems I'm missing a driver, or forgot something when compiling the kernel. But reading up on Grub2 and Gentoo documentation for a while now, I can't figure out what is missing, and how to troubleshoot this issue further.

And, for the record:

- Gentoo Base System release 2.2
- Linux kernel 3.10.25-gentoo
- After changing the `/etc/default/grub` file, I of course run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and check for the message '`Found linux image [..]`'.) to determine the change to `grub.cfg` was made successfully
- When I configure a higher resolution for grub2 only, and omit the `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` option, the system boots normally (in the default, low resolution). And grub2 uses the higher resolution correctly
- The resolution I want to use (`1024x768x32`) is listed in the grub2 `vbeinfo` output
- When I configure any value for `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX`, like `640x480x32`, the system also freezes when loading the kernel

Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to configure `GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1024x768x32`

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for your quick response! Tried that, didn't work. Also, I discovered that X wasn't installed correctly and didn't work. I have a working X now, and can run xterm in X. Bit ugly, but it works! But regarding a higher resolution console, after loading grub, I still have the exact same symptoms I described in my original post. I just want the same high res loading screen the LiveCD produces, y'know? Will update this post as soon as I find out more. Thanks!

Comment: Still not working. X works, I even have KDE running now, but no joy with starting the console in a higher resolution, still same issue as original post.
I would think that I've got all necessary support built into my kernel, since grub2 does boot in a the wanted resolution of 1024x768x32?
I'm rebuilding my kernel from scratch and playing with some options, just to be sure... But no joy so far.

Comment: You are running it as a guest OS in Virtual Box. Did you try to run Live CD as a guest as well and resolution was fine? Or you run Live CD directly on your computer?

Comment: I run it as a guest as well. But I think I found it..

Answer (score 1):

It's working :) I fixed two things:

Firstly, `/etc/conf.d/modules` was missing several lines, most importantly:

```
modules="vboxsf"
modules="vboxvideo"
modules="vboxguest"
```

.. After adding those, grub2 would finally load the kernel, and rc would automatically boot kdm. (I thought I had those lines, but apparantly, something went wrong saving that file earlier.)

Lastly, I recompiled the kernel with the following option enabled:

```
Device Drivers -> Graphics support 
-> Enable Support for frame buffer devices ->  VESA VGA Graphics support
```

.. After that, I'm seeing the standard linux boot output (starting all services etc.), but this time in a higher resolution.

By the way, I found this article very helpful:

http://blog.jolexa.net/2008/07/howto-gentoo-guest-os-in-virtualbox/

All in all a very useful exercise with Grub, Gentoo and compiling :)